# REST request to AWS from Quarkus backend

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, authentication, quarkus, aws-iot

I have to send a HTTP request to AWS IoT core to update device shadow. This request should send through Quarkus backend. **The current problem is how to Append Authentication headers to the request**. Currently there is a authentication problem with this code.

This is the Class used to send the request

```
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/things/abc")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RegisterRestClient(baseUri = "https://a144gttuytyty10wv7-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
public interface OrganizationProxy {

@GET
@Path("/shadow?name=shadow-version-1")
Uni<JsonObject> getOrg();

}
```

This is the client class for test sample get request

```
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/organizations")
@ApplicationScoped
public class OrganizationResource {


@Inject
@RestClient
OrganizationProxy organizationProxy;


@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Uni<JsonObject> get() {
return organizationProxy.getOrg();
}

}
```

I already try to append the Authentication headers. But I didn't found a way to how to do this in the program.  My final goal is to send a request to this AWS IoT core device API and get a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected with AWS Iot Core Device Shadow Rest end point with AWS SignV4.

https://github.com/kavishkamk/AWS-IoT-Core-REST-endpont-with-AWSV4

Answer (score 0):

Do you plan to use X509 certificate-based authentication or leveraging IAM access key and secret (see [Client authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/client-authentication.html))?

I recommend to leverage an existing SDK instead of building on your own. E.g. you can add this library as a Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk.iotdevicesdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-iot-device-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and directly use the classes. See https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java-v2 for samples.